# Changing the User Control by binding

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls

I have two `UserControl's`,

I would like, depending on the value in my ViewModel, to display another UserControl each time.

They are supposed to sit in `UserControl` that wraps them.

How can I do this?

**Here the wrapper:**

```
<UserControl>
    <local:UserControl1></local:UserControl1>// I want it to change by a binding
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with a DataTrigger. This is from memory but might help you along:

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <local:UserControl1 />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BoolProperty}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <local:UserControl2 />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: May need to add a TargetType to the Style. I typed that entire answer using the on-screen keyboard of this Surface RT. Wasn't easy! 

Comment: One more question, what is the TargetType should be in this line:`<Style>`? When I do `UserControl` it gives me an error.

Comment: TargetType will be `ContentControl`.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a bool property `BoolProperty` in your ViewModel and based on that value you can toggle the visibilty of other control using `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` -

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
       <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <local:UserControl1 Visibility="{Binding BoolProperty, Converter=
                                {StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Whenever the value of `BoolProperty` will be `true`, your control will be `visible` and in case of `false` will be `collapsed`.

Comment: I thought about it, There is no way to change the object itself?

Comment: What do you mean by `change the object itself`?

Comment: I mean that I will not hold two objects and then one will present, and the two hide. I want to hold one object and change its type, is it possible?

Comment: @HodayaShalom Have you considered using DataTemplates that target your specific class type? For example if you had a listbox showing Pets, and you wanted to specify a different view/usercontrol for cats and dogs, you could have a DataTemplate targetting cats and a different one targetting dogs. Here's a simple and contrived example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000771/binding-tabcontrol-to-observablecollection-with-different-content/15001298#15001298